# How to bundle files together in a program?

Tags: python, macos

In python i made a file with a lot of different functions, and i imported into another programming(.py) file to use, but then when i tried to make the application using py2app the application couldn't find the function file. How do i make it so that the function file and the programming file are included in the application as 1 (python isnt the only language i've tried this in, it's just an example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you specify an includes for external libs you want to force to be packaged:

http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/building-mac-os-x-applications-py2app/

```
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': ['EXTERNAL LIBRARY'],}
```